# Insert movie_id to subtitle of the episode they belong to PHP

Tags: php, foreach

My question is how do i give my subtitles a movie_id from the episode the belong to? i have tried using foreach with php.

```
foreach ($_POST['episodes'] as $episodes => $value ) {
    $episode_title = $value['episode_title'];
    $sql_episode = "INSERT INTO episode VALUES ('', '$episode_title', '$description', '$cover_id')";
    if ($db->query($sql_episode) === TRUE) {
        $inserted_id_episodes = $db->insert_id;
    }
}

foreach ($_POST['subtitles'] as $subtitles => $value ) {
    $subtitle_language = $value['subtitle_language'];
    $sql_subtitle = "INSERT INTO added_subtitle VALUES ('', '$subtitle_language', '$inserted_id_episodes')";
    $result = $db->query($sql_subtitle);
}
```

Javascript to add subtitles and episode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

var counter = 1;

$("#btn-addepisode").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(".add_episodes").append('<div class="add_episode_out"><div class="season_episode"><input type="text" placeholder="Episode titel" name="episodes['+counter+'][episode_title]"><i class="fa fa-trash delete-episode"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Indtast filnavn på episoden f.eks. orphan_black"><input class="fileextension_movie_season" type="text" placeholder=".mp4" disabled><h5>Vælg episode billede bredde 182px højde 102px</h5><input type="file" name="episode_image"><div class="subtitle_out"></div><button class="btn-addsubtitle">Tilføj undertekst</button></div></div>');
counter = counter + 1;
initRemove();
});

var initRemove = function() {
$(".delete-episode").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.add_episode_out').find(".season_episode").remove();
  counter = counter - 1;
  if (counter < 1) {
    counter = 1;
  }
});
}

});

$(document).ready(function() {

var counter = 1;

$('.add_episodes').on('click', '.btn-addsubtitle', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('.season_episode').find(".subtitle_out").append('<div class="add_subtitle_out"><div class="add_subtitle"><input type="text" placeholder="Undertekstsprog" name="subtitles['+counter+'][subtitle_language]><i class="fa fa-trash delete-subtitle"></i><h5>Vælg undertekstfil (filtype .vtt)  </h5><input type="file"></div></div>');
counter = counter + 1;
initRemove();
});

var initRemove = function() {
$(".delete-subtitle").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.add_subtitle_out').find(".add_subtitle").remove();
  counter = counter - 1;
  if (counter < 1) {
    counter = 1;
  }
});
}

});
</script>
```

This is what i am looking for:
[image]

I hope that someone know how this is done. Thanks.
Sorry for the ugly drawing!:)

Comment: How, or by whom, are the subtitles added 'dynamicly'?

Comment: added the javascript code to add subtitles and episodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your javascript generate a form like this:

```
<form  action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="episodes[0][episode_title]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="episodes[0][subtitle_language][]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="episodes[0][subtitle_language][]" value="">

  <input type="text" name="episodes[1][episode_title]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="episodes[1][subtitle_language][]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="episodes[1][subtitle_language][]" value="">

</form>
```

After that you can do something like this in php:

```
foreach ($_POST['episodes'] as $episodes => $value ) {
    $episode_title = $value['episode_title'];
    $sql_episode = "INSERT INTO episode VALUES ('', '$episode_title', '$description', '$cover_id')";
    if ($db->query($sql_episode) === TRUE) {

        $inserted_id_episodes = $db->insert_id;

        foreach ($value['subtitle_language'] as $subtitle_language) {

          $sql_subtitle = "INSERT INTO added_subtitle VALUES ($inserted_id_episodes, '$subtitle_language', '$inserted_id_episodes')";
          $result = $db->query($sql_subtitle);
        }
    }

}
```

So if you want to send the path of the subtitle you need your javascript generate a form like this:

```
  <form  action="" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="episodes[0][episode_title]" value="">

    <input type="text" name="episodes[0][subtitle][0][language]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="episodes[0][subtitle][0][path]" value="">

    <input type="text" name="episodes[0][subtitle][1][language]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="episodes[0][subtitle][1][path]" value="">

    <input type="text" name="episodes[1][episode_title]" value="">

    <input type="text" name="episodes[1][subtitle][0][language]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="episodes[1][subtitle][0][path]" value="">


  </form>
```

And change the phpcode:

```
foreach ($_POST['episodes'] as $episodes => $value ) {
    $episode_title = $value['episode_title'];
    $sql_episode = "INSERT INTO episode VALUES ('', '$episode_title', '$description', '$cover_id')";
    if ($db->query($sql_episode) === TRUE) {

        $inserted_id_episodes = $db->insert_id;

        foreach ($value['subtitle'] as $subtitle) {
          $path = $subtitle['path'];
          $language = $subtitle['language'];
          $sql_subtitle = "INSERT INTO added_subtitle VALUES ($inserted_id_episodes, $language, $path, $inserted_id_episodes)";
          $result = $db->query($sql_subtitle);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, i have tried your code, but it does not work, :/ (made a new 'test.php'  file to try out the code, but it does not work :/

Comment: Sorry! I made a few mistakes. I changed the code of the html(removed the single quotes from the key names) as well as the code of the php. This time I tested it.

Comment: what if i want to add a subtitle path also inside the foreach for the subtitles ? like $subtitle_path

Comment: the same way as $subtitle_language, but I don't know how to insert the value in the foreach :)

Comment: At the bottom of my answer I added an example to answer the question about subtitle path. Have a nice day

Comment: I'm not sure if you see this Redoneben, but can you check this one out, it seems like you know exactly what you are doing, it's about how i combine a foreach $_POST and foreach $_FILES